# Dataproc pyspark job total bytes billed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery, dataproc

I have a pyspark job that I submitted via dataproc. I would like to know how much data did my job use, or in other words, how much is GCP going to bill me.

I looked at the information schema table, those dont show the jobs run via dataproc.

I am looking for all the resources used by a particular dataproc job. Say I triggered a spark job and that loads some data from BQ and uses storage to store it temporarily. GCP will charge me cluster run time + BQ + storage. How can I get a trace of all the charges given a job uuid?

Answer (score 0):

is your question about how much dataproc will cost you?
if so it depends on the vCPUs of your dataproc cluster.

see this https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/pricing gives away the pricing calculator.

if you question is about dataproc processing data to/from BigQuery, you can use the bigquery --dry run option to run the same query that dataproc is issuing. here's link.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dry-run-queries

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have been more clearer. I am looking for all the resources used by a particular dataproc job. Say I triggered a spark job and that loads some data from BQ and uses storage to store it temporarily. GCP will charge me cluster run time + BQ + storage. How can I get a trace of all the charges given a job uuid?

Comment: Okay understood. I had similar requirement and the way we did it was by tagging the known resources and then enabling cloud billing export to bigquery. So lets say in your case if you create a unique tag for your resource groups ( cluster, bq and storage) you can enable its export to bigquery. we followed this blog . Hope this answers                                                       
 https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/cost-management/use-labels-to-gain-visibility-into-gcp-resource-usage-and-spending